# Can't override CSS directive with caret selector

Tags: javascript, css, dom, css-selectors, dom-events

I have an SVG file (inline in an HTML page) with about **60 buttons**.

Each of them has **two additional states**, each of which has an ID of the form:

```html
<g id="mov0-1"><!-- mouseover state -->
<g id="mod0-1"><!-- mousedown state -->
```

Initially the mouseover and mousedown states are **hidden in CSS**:

```css
g[id^='mod'] { display: none; }
g[id^='mov'] { display: none; }
```

When there is a mouseover, the state *should* change, using this function:

```
var obj = document.getElementById('link' + c + '-' + x);
obj.addEventListener('mouseover', mov.bind(null, x, c), false); 
...
function mov(x, c){
  var obj_id = 'mov' + c + '-' + x;
  var obj = document.getElementById(obj_id);
  obj.style.display = 'block';
}
```

**The above function fails.** However, if I replace the CSS caret with a list of individual buttons, **the function works**:

```css
g#mov1-0{display:none;}
g#mod1-0{display:none;}
```

**Why is this happening?**

Is there a way I can keep my elegant two-line solution that hides 120 buttons instead of having to list them all separately?

**N.B.** the SVG's are generated automatically by Adobe Illustrator, and I can't use **CSS classes**.

Comment: You can toggle a class using JS.

Comment: when you say "function fails" what do you mean exactly? is there an error of some kind you can see in the console or it just doesn't update the style visually?

Comment: Gert B, can you explain how I would get the class to apply to an SVG that I can't modify?

Comment: tromgy, it just fails to update the style. I tried using "block !important" but it didn't work. I'll do more research to see if I can find an error message anywhere.

Comment: I'm not sure what's really going on in here, But when a change in a selector fixes the issue suggests a specificity issue, If you could put up a working example for people to test out it would be much easier to figure out.

Comment: I tried to create a working example but couldn't reproduce the bug. In making the example code evolve towards the real code, I realized my boneheaded mistake (see answer).

Answer (score 1):

So it was a boneheaded mistake.

The parent objects *also* had ID's that began with **mov** and **mot**, so when I hid the unused buttons, I *also* hid their parent containers.

Lesson 1: **be careful with wildcards**.

Lesson 2: **when something breaks, don't assume it's because of some elaborate technical thing instead of a stupid error**.

Lesson 3: **build a simple test case to reproduce the problem**.

Renaming the parent containers (Illustrator layers) fixed the problem.